# How to display data from table 1 separately, and combined with matching rows from table 2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, view

I have two tables, let's call them `t1` and `t2`. They're associated - column `c1` in `t2` matches the primary key column `i1` in `t1`.

For my results, I want every row in `t1` to appear without any `t2` data; then, in the following output rows, I want to see the combined data from the `t1` row and any matching `t2` rows. Is that possible in MS SQL? How can I do it?

```
Table t1:   Table t2:
+----+----+  +----+----+----+
| i1 | x  |  | i2 | c1 | c2 |
+----+----+  +----+----+----+
| 1  | a  |  | 1  | 1  |    |
| 2  | b  |  | 2  | 2  | g  |
| 3  | c  |  | 3  | 3  | h  |
| 4  | d  |  | 4  | 3  | i  |
+----+----+  +----+----+----+

Result
+----+----+----+---+----+----+
| i  | i1 | i2 | x  |c1 | c2 |
+----+----+----+---+----+----+
| 1  |  1 |NULL| a |NULL|NULL|<-- `t1` First Row
| 2  |  1 | 1  | a | 1  |NULL|
| 3  |  2 |NULL| b |NULL|NULL|<-- `t1` Second Row
| 4  |  2 | 2  | b | 2  | g  |
| 5  |  3 |NULL| c |NULL|NULL|<-- `t1` Third Row
| 6  |  3 | 3  | c | 3  | h  |
| 7  |  3 | 4  | c | 3  | i  |
| 8  |  4 |NULL| d |NULL|NULL|<-- `t1` Fourth Row
+----+----+----+---+----+----+
```

NOTE: column `i` in the output is simply a row number.

Comment: Please post what you've written so far in your attempts to create the view - we need to know how you're joining `T1` to `T2`.  Also, in your Result, there is a new column called 'i' - where did that come from?

Comment: @ScottHodgin i am so sorry for not explain `i`, it's just row number for seperate the values. I tried the all join commands but i didn't get any solution

Comment: I'm also confused why the last row in your result has a col-x of 'c' and why there doesn't seem to be a row in resut with a col-x of 'd'.  What columns are you using to join these tables?

Comment: I think there should be a 9th row containing the values `9  |  4 | 4  | d | 3  | i  |` and row 7 should be `7  |  3 | 3  | c  | 3  | h  |`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing (in particular around the joins), does this look something like what you are looking for?

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (i1 INT, x CHAR(1));
CREATE TABLE T2 (i2 INT, c1 INT, c2 CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO T1 (i1, x) VALUES
(1,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(3,'c'),
(4,'d');

INSERT INTO T2 (i2, c1, c2) VALUES
(1,1,''),
(2,2,'g'),
(3,3,'h'),
(4,3,'i');
GO

CREATE VIEW TestView 
AS
WITH cteInitialSet AS (
    SELECT i1, NULL AS i2, x, NULL AS c1, NULL AS c2 FROM dbo.T1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T1.i1, T2.i2, T1.x, T2.c1, T2.c2 
    FROM dbo.T1
        JOIN dbo.T2 ON T1.i1 = T2.c1
        )

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i1, i2) AS i,
    i1 ,
    i2 ,
    x ,
    c1 ,
    c2
FROM cteInitialSet
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.TestView;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know an answer was already picked over a year ago, and it's a good answer. But I was browsing and I saw this as a fun challenge to figure out, and I figured I might as well share my code since I took the time to write it.

Here's what I came up with. From what I can see, you essentially want some sort of a "header" row...so I used GROUPING SETS...It basically works the same way as @Nic's solution...but instead of doing a union, I'm duplicating the data with GROUPING SETS. Since you're not using any aggregates, the second grouping set just returns all records from t1 with everything else null.

So I started off by figuring out the two sets of data you want to combine:

```
--Thanks @Nic for the sample data :)
CREATE TABLE #T1 (i1 INT, x CHAR(1));
CREATE TABLE #T2 (i2 INT, c1 INT, c2 CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO #T1 (i1, x) VALUES (1,'a'), (2,'b'), (3,'c'), (4,'d');
INSERT INTO #T2 (i2, c1, c2) VALUES (1,1,''), (2,2,'g'), (3,3,'h'), (4,3,'i');

GO

SELECT i = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.i1, x.i2, x.x)
    , x.i1, x.i2, x.x, x.c1, x.c2
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.i1, t2.i2, t1.x, t2.c1, t2.c2
    FROM #T1 t1
        LEFT JOIN #T2 t2 ON t1.i1 = t2.c1
--                           Data Rows                           Header Rows
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((t1.i1, t2.i2, t1.x, t2.c1, t2.c2), (t1.i1, t1.x))
) x
```